# Coloring table rows considering field value

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I'm working on a corporate website in which you retrieve (via a MySQL consult) some data that are formatted on a HTML table. The problem comes when trying to change the row color if a specific field value is one or another.

The (partial) code is:

```
    $RowCt = 0;
while($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result))
{   
    $timezone = new DateTimeZone( "Europe/London" );
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->setTimezone( $timezone );
    $ahora = $date->format( 'H:i' ); 

    if ($var == 1) {
        $rowcolor = "red";
    } else if ($var == 0) {
        $rowcolor = "yellow";
    } else {
        $rowcolor = "white";
    }

    //$Table.= "<tr style='background-color:#FFFFFF;'>";

    foreach($Row as $field => $value)
    {                   
        switch ($field) {
            default:
                $Table.= "<td style='font-size:14px; background-color:$rowcolor' align='center'>$value</td>"; 
                break;  
            case a:          
                if ($now > $value) {
                        $var == 0;
                    } else {    
                        // Do nothing
                    }
                $Table.= "<td style='font-size:14px; background-color:$rowcolor' align='center'>$value</td>"; 
                break;
            case b:
                if ($now > $value) {
                        $var == 1;
                    } else {    
                        // Do nothing
                    }
                $Table.= "<td style='font-size:14px; background-color:$rowcolor' align='center'>$value</td>"; 
                break;
            case c:
                switch ($value) {
                    case 1:
                        $Table.= "<td style='font-size:14px; background-color:$rowcolor' align='center'>a</td>";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $Table.= "<td style='font-size:14px; background-color:$rowcolor' align='center'>b</td>";
                        break;
                }
            case d:
                switch ($value) {
                    case 3:
                        $Table.= "<td style='font-size:14px; background-color:$rowcolor' align='center'>a</td>";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        $Table.= "<td style='font-size:14px; background-color:$rowcolor' align='center'>b</td>";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        $Table.= "<td style='font-size:14px; background-color:$rowcolor' align='center'>c</td>";
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        $Table.= "<td style='font-size:14px; background-color:$rowcolor' align='center'>d</td>";
                        break;
                }
            case e:
                switch ($value) {
                    case "E":
                        $Table.= "<td style='font-size:14px; background-color:$rowcolor' align='center'>a</td>";
                        break;
                    case "I":
                        $Table.= "<td style='font-size:14px; background-color:$rowcolor' align='center'>b</td>";
                        break;
                    case "F":
                        $Table.= "<td style='font-size:14px; background-color:$rowcolor' align='center'>c</td>";
                        break;
                }
        }
    }
$Table.= "</tr>";
```

The problem comes when trying to define a value inside of the switch statement, and then trying to make it be a condition so the entire row is colored (yellow if case 1 is selected and we aren't on time; red if case 2 is selected and we aren't on time).

Comment: Why are you doing `$var == 0;`? The assignment operator is a single  `=`, only when comparing the double is used.

Comment: your switch statement makes a very little sense. can you describe it's meaning?

Comment: Also, your three `$Table.= ` statements are identical - if this is the point, move them out of your switch. You might want to add a different `$rowcolor` per case, too...

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Changed the `$var` to a single '='. The `$Table.=` statements are defined that way for a posterior `return $Table;` in where the entire table is printed.

Comment: what is the $now and $value outputting? try var_dump($now) and var_dump($value) to see if your if statement is doing what you think it is. then you will know if the 2 are even comparable. Often times the values in the fields for dates are weird depending on how your db server is setup and what type the fields are.

Comment: About the `switch` statement: The function loops through the SQL results, and I've used a `switch` condition in order to print a different `<td>` values for each `$field` on the table.

Comment: @darkveloper - `$now` is outputting the result of `$date->format( 'H:i' );` for London timezone; `$value` is outputting the `$field` value. I do really believe that they are comparable, as the `$field` value is an SQL return that is on the same `H:i` format. Even thought, will make a try on that dump.

Comment: @darkveloper - `var_dump($now);` returns a `string(5) "H:i"` (considering the actual time) and `var_dump($value);` returns also a string for each defined values. On the `$db_explo` or `$db_obj` cases it also returns the same `string(5) "H:i"`.

Comment: Does it literally return H:i or the time itself?

Comment: It returns literally H:i, i.e. 14:45.

Comment: Edited with the original `while` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code snippet doesnt really explain much, but from i can see, i would advise your switch differently. Your switch is building HTML output.

I would encourage using switch to rather set the style in a $style variable, also... strictly speaking it makes better logic to use case: first and then default: eg.

```
switch ($condition) {
  case 1 : $style = 'background:red;'; break;
  case 2 : $style = 'background:yellow;'; break;
  default : $style = 'background:white;';
}
```

now build your HTML eg.

```
foreach ($results as $row) echo '<tr><td style="'.$style.'">Cell data</td></tr>';
```

For multiple cases on switch:

```
switch ($condition) {
  case 0:
  case 1:
    // Do something
    break;
  case 2: /* Do something */ break;
  default: /* Do something */ break;
}
```

2 Tier switch:

```
switch ($condition_1) {
  case 0 :
    switch ($condition_2) {
      case 'A' :
      // do something
      break;
    }
  break;
}
```

Don't forget to BREAK in both levels

Comment: This is odd. I've added your `switch` for `$var`, and looks like it paints it all on yellow (first case) even if the condition (`$var = 0`) is not true at the moment. Unfortunately, I need that switch statement for a multiple definition that goes below.

Comment: Hi alex, i've added a usage example for multiple cases in the switch, its a bit odd that the switch will always use the 1st case. I would check and make sure you are using BREAK; after each case, as well as make sure you know the value of $var

Comment: As per your edit, you have a 2 tier nested switch, the 1st tier is not BREAK-ing, 2nd switches are...

Comment: Uhmm. Added the `break;` for the first nested switch on both cases, and still paints it all on yellow. Tried also to `global $var;` before the first switch in case it wasn't being exported correctly, but dunno.

Comment: Testing the coloring, and making `$var = 1`, now it paints all but the first row (the one that should be painted) on yellow. (Considering a modified code, `$var = 1;` for yellow, `$var = 2;` for red; and `if ($var == 1) { $rowcolor = "yellow"; } else if ($var == 2) { $rowcolor = "red"; } else { $rowcolor = "white"; }` Looks like it isn't identifying correctly the `$var`.

Comment: From your code i can tell where $var is defined, as i said earlier, i think you should double check the source/value of $var, before scrutinizing the switch code block.

Comment: Got it working with session values, even thought it doesn't seems to color correctly a single row. Thanks for all the help, will keep it on with other approach.